# problem in installing studio code without sudo in linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

As someone new to Linux, I've been attempting to install Visual Studio Code without using sudo, as the administrator hasn't updated the old version, and I need to run the latest one.

I extracted the tar.gz file into my home directory, but whenever I attempt to launch it using either 'code' or './bin/code', the outdated version of Visual Studio Code launches instead.

It seems that the system is executing '/usr/bin/code' instead of the updated version located in '/home/myhome/VSCode/bin/code'.

I've already examined my $PATH and aliases, but haven't found any issues.

What steps can I take to resolve this issue?

Comment: delete `/usr/bin/code`, then add `/home/myhome/VSCode/bin` to $PATH or install the new version in `/usr/bin`, whys it in `/home/myhome` ?

Comment: I don't have sudo and can't delete usr/bin/code or install the new version in '/usr/bin'. I tried to add 'home/[my account name]/VSCode/bin' to $PATH but 'old version' is executed. I tried to 'alias mycode='home/[my account name]/VSCode/bin/code' and run 'mycode' in terminal but nothing happens.

Comment: When you added your new one to the path, how did you do it? Show it in your question post. Did you prepend it? Or did you append? You should prepend it so that it gets found ahead of the old one.

Comment: I appended it before and that is why old version launched as you commented. I tried to prepend it as 'PATH=~/VSCode/bin:$PATH' but nothing happens (no launching studio code windos) when I use 'code' command in terminal. I am using linux machine through remote desktop connection from windows.

Comment: Nothing happens? No "Command "code" not found" message? No activity in your system monitor application (if you have one)? No seemingly unresponsive prompt that you need to `ctrl+c` to get control of the prompt back again? No error message? No non-zero response code?

Comment: I tried to do 'code --verbose' to know what the issue is and "FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /home/[user name]/VSCode/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755."  I tried to do 'chmod 4755 chrom-sandbox' but it is not fixed (I have no idea sudo is required to chmod files in my home directory). so I launch studio code without sandboxing by 'code --no-sandbox'. It works now but I am not sure whether sandboxing is important or not.

Comment: Related writeup: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/11/28/vscode-sandbox